# Output Strings from a file

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to read a Strings from txt file and output them on the screen

```
FILE *ipfileptr;
char wordsInFile[50] = { 0 };

//Open file
fopen_s(&ipfileptr, "Input.txt", "r");

if (ipfileptr == NULL) {
    printf("File does not exist");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    fscanf_s(ipfileptr, "%s", &wordsInFile[i]);
    printf("Words in file: %s\n", wordsInFile[i]);
}

//Close file
fclose(ipfileptr);
```

Sadly all I'm getting is:

- Words in file: null
- Words in file: null
- Words in file: null

I feel like I'm missing something basic and can't figure out myself. I'm sure that my file name is correct. Text file contains names: john tom jay

Comment: `fscanf_s(ipfileptr, "%s", wordsInFile,50); printf("Words in file: %s\n", wordsInFile);`

Comment: Step through with a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char wordsInFile[50]` is an array of 50 characters.  It is not an array of 50 strings.

You will need to declare it as `char* wordsInFile[50]`, and then before reading each line you will have to allocate memory for it with `malloc()`.

Also, the documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5hh6ee9.aspx says that you should always check the return value of `fopen_s()` for errors, and it seems to be indicating that the value of your `ipfileptr` will be left unchanged in the event of an error.  If `ipfileptr` was declared at file scope, it will usually be pre-initialized to null, so in the event of an error it will stay null.  But if the code you are showing us is inside a function, then `ipfileptr` will probably contain garbage, and garbage is usually non-null, so you would not know that an error occurred.

Also, as Weather Vane and chqrlie point out in comments, you also need to pass the size of your buffer to `fscanf_s`.  The main difference between `fscanf` and `fscanf_s` is that `fscanf_s` requires the size in characters of your buffer to be passed as an argument immediately following the buffer argument.  Documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx

So, your `fscanf_s` call should have looked like this: `fscanf_s(ipfileptr, "%s", wordsInFile[i], size);` (where `size` is the number of characters that have been allocated for `wordsInFile[i]`.)

Comment: Also tell the OP to pass `fscanf_s` the size of the destination buffer for  the `%s` format.

Comment: @chqrlie wow, I did not even notice that, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Your explanation is somewhat confusing: you use `50` for both the number of strings (as per the OP's choice), and the size of each string, that should therefore be allocated with `malloc(50)`.  It would be clearer to use different numbers so the OP can tell which is which.

Comment: @chqrlie I think that would be the least of the OP's concerns, but in principle you are right.  I will fix that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

clang is quite helpful here, although since you are printing the word in the file immediately I don't see any reason to dynamically allocate memory as suggested by Mike (unless you want to save the words for later...).  All you really need is a `char*` instead of a `char` when passing then word into `printf`.

```
main.c:17:39: warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char' [-Wformat]
    printf("Words in file: %s\n", wordsInFile[i]);
                           ~~     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                           %c
```

should be something like:

```
printf("Words in file: %s\n", &wordsInFile[i]);
```

will result in: (its weird since your loop goes 50 times but Input.txt has 3 words)

```
Words in file: john
Words in file: tom
Words in file: jay
Words in file: ay
Words in file: y
Words in file:
Words in file:
...
Words in file:
```

Comment: Does `clang` also complain about the argument mismatch for `fscanf_s()`?

Comment: clang couldn't find fscanf_s or fopen_s since I compiled it on linux, so I'm not sure, I substituted them for the legacy fscanf and fopen calls.

Comment: `fopen_s()` is not very useful indeed, but `fscanf_s()` is such an improvement on `fscanf()`!  C11 specifies this as an extension, it is too bad dogmatism seems to reign on both sides (failing C99 support on Windows / Silly refusal of useful extensions on Linux and OS/X)